# Allocating a larger u-boot image

Tags: linux-kernel, environment-variables, bootloader, u-boot, beagleboard

I am compiling my own kernel and bootloader (U-boot). I added a bunch of new environmental variables, but U-boot doesn't load anymore (it just doesn't load anything from the memory). I am using pocketbeagle and booting from an SD card. Thus I am editing the file "am335x_evm.h" found in /include/configs/.

I am trying to allocate U-boot in a way that it has more space for the environmental variables and that it can load succesfully from the memory, but I have been unable to do so. As far as I understand, by default it allocates 128kb of memory to U-boot env variables. Since I added a bunch of them, I am trying to increase its size from 128kb to 512kb.

I have changed the following line (from 128kb to 512kb):

```
#define CONFIG_ENV_SIZE         (512 << 10)
```

*(By the way, anyone knows why it is shifted to the left 10 bits?)*

I have also changed CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET and CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET_REDUND  to:

```
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET       (1152 << 10) /* Originally 768 KiB in */
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET_REDUND    (1664 << 10) /* Originally 896 KiB in */
```

Then after compiling the new U-boot, I format the SD card and insert the new kernel and U-boot.

I start by erasing partitions:

```
export DISK=/dev/mmcblk0
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=${DISK} bs=1M count=10
```

Then I transfer U-boot by doing:

```
sudo dd if=./u-boot/MLO of=${DISK} count=1 seek=1 bs=512k
sudo dd if=./u-boot/u-boot.img of=${DISK} count=2 seek=1 bs=576k
```

I then create the partition layout by doing:

```
sudo sfdisk ${DISK} <<-__EOF__
4M,,L,*
__EOF__
```

Then I add the kernel, binary trees, kernel modules, etc... When trying to boot and reading the serial port, I get nothing at all. U-boot is not able to load anything from the SD card. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate if you could point me what my problem is and exactly what I should be doing to increase the size and allocate everything correctly.

Comment: Shifting left by 10 is the same as multiplying by 2^10 = 1024.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Have you used your original version of U-Boot to accurately calculate how much environment space you're using?  Quadrupling the space is ridiculous.  There's no reason to change `CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET`.  IMO with SDcard, you would be better off creating a partition on the SDcard after the U-Boot image, and using a VFAT filesystem to store the env variables as a file.

Comment: Well I am actually using a lot of space in env variables, almost 4 times to original size. It's actually a lot... Yeah I thought about just doing that in the uEnv.txt file instead, but I still need to increase its size to 512kb. I am not sure where to do that. I saw a specific line in the code "#define FAT_ENV_FILE   "uboot.env"", apparently there is that file that controls the env variables' settings of the SD card (and I guess uEnv.txt to store the actual variables), but I couldn't find uboot.env anywhere!

Comment: *" I am actually using a lot of space in env variables"* -- Then you're probably abusing the concept of environment variables.  If these are scripts, then they probably should be organized into loadable script files.

Comment: *"I get nothing at all. U-boot is not able to load anything"* -- You're not clear, and giving contradictory descriptions. Are you reporting that U-Boot SPL is getting loaded, and is executing? According to the TRM, you don't have to use `SD Card Raw Mode`, and instead can load the SPL (aka MLO) and u-boot.img from a VFAT filesystem. Of course you'll have to reconfigure U-Boot. See also the [AM335x U-Boot User's Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_U-Boot_User%27s_Guide).